# PreviewKeyDown only fires once

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In visual basic 2010 express, I was initially using the keyDown event to use arrows to control a picturebox, but it only fired when holding ctrl + arrowkey.. and the solution that i found online was to use the previewKeyDown event. This only fires once and then doesn't respond to any key presses at all.
KeyPreview has been set to true.

```
  Private Sub Form1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreviewKeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Up
            vy = vy - 2
        Case Keys.Left
            vx = vx - 2
        Case Keys.Right
            vx = vx + 2
    End Select
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Private Sub Form1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreviewKeyDown
```

To

```
Private Sub Form1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewKeyDown
```

Also try to add `e.Handled=True`

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Up
            vy = vy - 2
            e.Handled = True
        Case Keys.Left
            vx = vx - 2
            e.Handled = True
        Case Keys.Right
            vx = vx + 2
            e.Handled = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. Check if some other keydown event is active and changing the focus.

Comment: I opened another project and started off with the keydown event before adding in others and it works now for some reason. I'll add the handle flags in as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2 solutions proposed: 1st has no effect, 2nd neither as ME does not have focus, so never receives the keydown.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `KeyDown`, instead of `PreviewKeyDown`, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Up
            vy = vy - 2 
        Case Keys.Left
            vx = vx - 2
        Case Keys.Right
            vx = vx + 2                       
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: i have tried this, but when i execute the program i have to hold ctrl in order to use the arrow keys, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Picturebox does not have KeyDown event.